# graphlab not showing column image

Tags: machine-learning, graphlab, sframe

I have a image column in a SFrame along with an image_array column.

when I do

```
sframe['image'].show()
```

instead of showing the actual images it shows summary of the image column along with value,count and percent. How should I show the actual image when I call the show method?

Answer (score 1):

Set the show result to canvas in ipython notebook

```
graphlab.canvas.set_target('ipynb')
```

`sframe['image'].show()`

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword browser instead ipynb as below stated

```
graphlab.canvas.set_target('browser')
```